# Access to class member by multi threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

I made a class (parent class) with several variables on it.
This class is accessed by multiple threads. However, each variable is accessed by only a dedicated thread.

I was wondering, when a thread accesses a dedicated variable, this thread locks the parent class or it just locks the accessed variable?

Comment: Post your actual code.  Classes don't have variables. They have properties that may or may not be backed by fields. Fields are just implementation details, never part of the class's API. There are no dedicated properties, much less fields and no implicit locking. You need to *design* your code to be thread-safe

Comment: If the properties are read-only, they're thread-safe simply because the value can't be changed by other threads. It's a lot easier to write thread-safe code when a class is immutable.

Comment: If you haven't explicitly implemented some sort of locking there is none. If locking is needed or not depends so there is no real "common" answer. Accessing is typically no problem, changing is.

Comment: Unless you specifically modify the variable within a lock or it is an immutable variable, it is not thread safe.

Comment: *"I made a class (parent class) with several variables on it"* -- Could you edit the question and clarify if you mean [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) or [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)?

Comment: *"However, each variable is accessed by only a dedicated thread."* -- Are you sure about that? No other thread is ever going to read the variable, other than its dedicated thread?

Comment: As others have said, there are no variables at a class-level. Also, when a thread accesses a field or property there is no locking. You have to explicitly do the locking. What are you really asking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit locking in c#. If you need to lock something, use a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock). See also [interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-6.0) for some lower level methods that are sometimes useful.

Note that there are thread safety issues whenever there is any chance of concurrent reading and writing, or writing and writing, of memory. Easiest way to avoid this is to ensure there is no writing going on, i.e. use immutable objects and pure functions.

While your design sound safe since there is no concurrent read/writes to any single field, it is terrible usability, since the caller needs to follow some special rules.

By convention, static methods should be thread safe, while non static methods should be assumed non thread safe, unless otherwise specified.

- If a class is thread safe, any methods should be callable from any thread at any time.
- If a class is not thread safe, none of its methods should be used concurrently.

Also note that multi threaded programming is *difficult*. It is very easy to introduce bugs that only appear in very special circumstances, and therefore difficult to find. So I would recommend reading a fair bit about multi threading and thread safety before using any kind of multi threading for anything important.

Comment: That means there is no problem if each variable can be accessed by only a dedicated thread. Thank you very much.